# llvm: generating cleanup destructors before function return

Tags: c++, code-generation, return-value, llvm, local-variables

in LLVM, usually you will exit a generated function with `CreateRet`, however, i want to add cleanup destructors for local objects instantiated in the function.

My question is: i assume i have to insert the cleanup function calls *before* inserting the `CreateRet`, however, i'm wondering if the return value is one of the locals (suppose we are returning by value) then we cannot destruct this value before the return, but the local will not be destructed after the return either, so i would say i'm a bit confused about the lifetime of the locals and where to properly insert the cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can codegen your source-language `return` statement / expressions as copies into the return storage followed by a branch to a designated return basic block, which will destroy locals. If your generated LLVM function returns the value itself, instead of following its own protocol (by returning the value through the first parameter, or some such), you can save the return value to an `alloca` first, and then load that `alloca` and return that with `ret`. Example for when you return through the first parameter, with `%valuetype` denoting the struct storing values in your language runtime

```
define void @myfn(%valuetype *%ret) {
  ; use and create whatever locals you need

  ; source-language: return somelocal
  store %valuetype %local1, %valuetype *%ret
  br label %retlabel

retlabel:
  ; emit code to destruct locals ..., then return
  ret void
}
```

Comment: thanks @Johannes, what you mean with 'following its own protocol', what protocol you refer to?

Comment: @lurscher you may return values by using "ret", or you may return them by passing a pointer to the respective storage to the function and writing into that (as illustrated). That's what I mean by "protocol". If your language is dynamic, where the amount of parameters is determined dynamically, you also cannot map source language parameters to LLVM parameters but need to follow your "own protocol" here, too.

Answer (score 2):

Look at some C++ disassembly! :)
Generally, you save the return value on the stack, call the destructors of all local objects and then move the return value from the stack into the `eax` register (cdecl calling convention). The `eax` saving is necessary because the destructors are allowed to change that register.
Take this very hypothetical pseudo assembly for example:

```
// inside imaginary function
mov [ebp-0Ch],eax; // save eax register
lea ecx, [ebp-4]; // [ebp-4] == your object address
call Foo::~Foo(); // call the destructor
mov eax,[ebp-0Ch]; // retrieve the saved return value
ret; // now return
```

If the returned value is a local object, then you of course first need to copy the object into the prepared space.

```
// pseudo function call
int i = func();
```

Here, the space for the return value of `func` will be provided on the stack, and that's where you copy your return value. After that, proceed as shown above.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is that llvm doesn't let you see directly registers on the stack, the specific register allocation and manipulation is generated in the backend generators, my problem is how to encode the cleanup in the LLVM generation api when the return is passed by value and the type is not a POD

Comment: @lurscher: Sorry, don't really know about LLVM, thought you wanted to know what happens behind the scenes. :/ Maybe you can find a function to copy an object into the provided return space somehwere?

Comment: yes @Xeo, my hope is that there is some mechanism to retrieve the reference of the destination of the return value in the stack and write to it directly, however the examples in the example compiler Kaleidoscope doesn't do anything like this (because its a simple compiler, all types are PODs, so no cleanup is required)

Comment: @lurscher: Maybe `CreateRet` even does a cleanup? What does the documentation say?